# Subsonic 3 and Activerecord isn't generating MySQL Stored Procedures

Tags: mysql, activerecord, subsonic, subsonic3, subsonic-active-record

It seems that the included T4 templates (or the one in the SVN trunk for that matter) just skips generating SPs for MySQL...
When running StoredProcedures.ttinclude together with MySQL.ttinclude, I get the error "Compiling transformation: The name 'GetSPs' does not exist in the current context".

GetSPs is defined for SQLServer and I saw that someone wrote his own for Oracle, but does anyone have a clue how the proper GetSPs()-method should look like for MySQL?

Personally I don't think it's really functional unless I can run my own SPs :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tinkered around a bit with the code from version 2 and came up with a little code (probably not 100% in all situations) that did the trick for me. Put this in MySQL.ttinclude to get Stored Procedures generated. Enjoy!

```
string[] GetSPList()
{
    var result=new List();
    const string sql = "SELECT routine_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES WHERE ROUTINE_SCHEMA = ?databaseName";
    StringBuilder sList = new StringBuilder();

    using(conn=new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?databaseName", DatabaseName);
        conn.Open();
        using(IDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
        {
            bool isFirst = true;
            while(rdr.Read())
            {
                if(!isFirst)
                    sList.Append('|');
                isFirst = false;
                sList.Append(rdr[0]);
            }
            rdr.Close();
        }
    }
    return sList.ToString().Split(new char[] {'|'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
}

List GetSPParams(string spName)
{
    var result=new List();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
    using(conn=new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = spName;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        try
        {
            MySqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(cmd);
        }
        catch
        {
        }

        if(cmd.Parameters.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach(MySqlParameter param in cmd.Parameters)
            {
                SPParam p = new SPParam();
                p.SysType = GetSysType(param.MySqlDbType.ToString());
                p.DbType = param.DbType.ToString();
                p.Name = param.ParameterName;
                p.CleanName=CleanUp(p.Name);
                result.Add(p);
            }
        }
        conn.Close();
    }

    return result;
}

List GetSPs(){
    var result=new List();
    string[] spNames = GetSPList();

    foreach(string spName in spNames){
        var sp=new SP();
        sp.Name=spName;
        sp.CleanName=CleanUp(sp.Name);
        sp.Parameters=GetSPParams(sp.Name);
        result.Add(sp);        
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Would love it if you could fork/push this to us at Github!

Answer (score 1):

I got this code to run by adding it to my MySQL.ttinclude however I had to change the generic List's to typed lists. eg: `List<SPParam>` and `List<SP>`. The code worked after that though ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As per craig's answer, I changed the Lists to typed lists and I also needed to remove `var  result=new List();`  from the `GetSPList()` code block. Cheers